# Does JMS have a concept of a queue peek?

Tags: java, queue, jms, peek

From a general Computer Science perspective - when we think of a Queue in a logical sense - we think of being able to 'peek' the first item in the queue.

When I look at the JMS API - it has a `MessageListener` - which has an `OnMessage()` method. This feels a little bit like "don't call us- we'll call you."

Does JMS have a concept of a queue peek?

Comment: How are you planning to use this functionality?  You can read a message and roll it back which allows it to be seen in the queue again.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey - if you could post a link to an example of this then I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Turn off auto-commit.  This requires you to their commit() the message or rollback it. I don't know of any good examples, but a google might help.

Comment: actually, it would be very nice if JMS had some sort of queue peek, so if you want to pause your consumers, you could just check a flag before consuming the message. Or, if the message-driven bean could have some sort of a @beforeOnMessage method where you could just execute before actually consuming the message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) If you want to receive messages synchroneously use MessageConsumer.receive

2) Basically, 'peek' in queues means to return, but do not remove, the head of the queue. 
For this you can use [QueueBrowser](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncey/index.html) to look at messages on a queue without removing them.

Answer (score 0):

JMS has a [QueueReceiver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/QueueReceiver.html), which, well, receives messages. You can set a MessageListener to this QueueReceiver to be notified of new messages.